# overrided delete() method not working on all part of django admin

Tags: django, django-models

I have two tables in my Django model, Category and Image.

when I create a Category, an Image creates automatically, and when a Category deletes, The corresponding Image will be destroyed.

I override the `delete()` method in Category. It works correctly when I click delete button in the details page of the object (It removes corresponding Image objece):

[image: detail page]

But when I want to delete the Category object in the listed objects page:

[image]

[image]

It doesn't remove the corresponding Image object.

How can I fix this and delete every Category I selected and so that it removes every corresponding Image Objects?

My `models.py` is like:

```
from django.db.models import Q


class Image(models.Model):
    image_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='all/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s | %s' % (self.image_id, self.image)

class Category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    c_thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to='img/thumbnailCategory/', null=False, blank=False)

    def delete(self, **kwargs):
        image = Image.objects.get(Q(image_id=self.category_id))
        image.delete()
        super(Category, self).delete()

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Category, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
        # this will create or update an Image
        Image.objects.update_or_create(image_id=self.category_id, image=self.c_thumbnail)
        super(Category, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s | %s' % (self.title, self.category_id)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use signals to do this in your current database model. The issue comes with the way queryset deletes work, which the documentation explains [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects). When you delete a category using the list view, it does a queryset delete, which does NOT trigger the model's delete.

As you have things set up now, you can instead listen for the `post_delete` (or `pre_delete`) signal for `Category`. See the documentation on signals [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/)

All that said, there is an easier way to what you want:

make `image_id` into something meaningful like `category` and set it up as

```
category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then when you delete a `Category` object, it will also remove images with a foreign key relationship set to that `Category`. Much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, I changed image_id to category and it works now.

Comment: Glad it helped!